# Installing Pootle with uwsgi on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, django, uwsgi, virtualenv

I'm trying to install a Pootle server on an ubuntu server under uwsgi. While everything went ok on my local dev server, when online i got this error i cannot overcome. It seems application-related, not server related, but since it works on my (identical) dev server...holy grief...i have no idea!

tnx in advance!
gabriele

```
    [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from pootle.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 0.9.9-dev-1458-unbit (32bit) on [Fri Sep  2 18:53:36 2011] ***
compiled with version: 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4) on 29 August 2011 11:37:34
detected binary path: /opt/unbit/bin/uwsgi
your process address space limit is 67108864 bytes (64 MB)
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
uwsgi socket 0 inherited UNIX address /var/lib/apache2/upstream/13981_upstream.sock fd 0
Python version: 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jan 20 2010, 22:05:59)  [GCC 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu3)]
Set PythonHome to /accounts/gabriobald/www/translate.9thcircle.it
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x91cc2b8
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
added /accounts/gabriobald/www/ to pythonpath.
WSGI application 0 (mountpoint=) ready on interpreter 0x91cc2b8 pid: 16484 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 16484)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 16486, cores: 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/accounts/gabriobald/www/translate.9thcircle.it/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/accounts/gabriobald/www/translate.9thcircle.it/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware pootle_misc.middleware.baseurl: "No module named pootle_misc.middleware.baseurl"
[pid: 16486|app: 0|req: 1/1] 88.50.43.19 () {38 vars in 863 bytes} [Fri Sep  2 18:53:38 2011] GET / => generated 0 bytes in 167 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/accounts/gabriobald/www/translate.9thcircle.it/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 250, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/accounts/gabriobald/www/translate.9thcircle.it/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware pootle_misc.middleware.baseurl: "No module named pootle_misc.middleware.baseurl"
[pid: 16486|app: 0|req: 2/2] 88.50.43.19 () {36 vars in 794 bytes} [Fri Sep  2 18:53:38 2011] GET /favicon.ico => generated 0 bytes in 2 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Error importing middleware pootle_misc.middleware.baseurl: "No module named pootle_misc.middleware.baseurl"
```

This means that it cannot load the python code that's needed for the application.  Since django's running from site-packages, the `pootle_misc` module should probably be in there (or within a relative path would be fine, too).  Look for a `pootle_misc` directory within `/accounts/gabriobald/www/translate.9thcircle.it/lib/python2.5/site-packages/` - it's probably there on your dev system, and not on your live one.

Comment: tnx! i had not idea of the executing path...bit confusing, actually

Answer (score 0):

You must add more site dir in your wsgi.py:

```
  ...

  ALLDIRS = [
       '/usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
       '/usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/apps',
  ]

  for directory in ALLDIRS:
     site.addsitedir(directory)

  ...
```